# Table with Action Buttons Versus Turbotax Wizard-Like Experience

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

I am working with a team to develop a web application where people can come and request access to various intranet applications.

For the "Requestor" side of things, we have a Turbo-Tax wizard-like experience. The idea is this, we ask them a series of tailored questions about which application, environment (Production, Development, or Staging), and specifically about the application they are requesting. Based on each answer to the question we tailor the next question.

At the end of the process we build the request and send the request to an approver.

This is where we are stuck UX-wise. The approval process is presented as a grid where the approvers see a listing of all of the requests. They then have a button at the end of each row in the grid where they can click on said button. That button leads to a popup where they can see details of the request and approve/deny the request along with an optional comment.

As a team we felt that we can have a wizard-like experience for the approval process as well to make things easy to use for both requestors and approvers but we are out of ideas.

Hope folks here have an idea on how we can approach this.

Thank you for your time.

### EDIT

Screens for Requestors:

[image: Mockup Third Page for Requestor]

Screen for Approvers:

[image: Mockup Page for Approver]

Comment: Can you share any existing wireframes to help communicate?

Comment: @Midas Sure, I will put a few up

Comment: @Midas Added UI Mockups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very close to identifying the solution. The Requester and the Approver have different goals, so can use different tools to meet those goals. For example, the Requester can use a wizard to capture information (because Wizards are very good at guiding users though complex or critical things), and the Approver works from a list and is approving/declining requests one at time as they review each request.